# excel formula for time stamp extraction

Tags: excel, excel-formula

example 8/19/16 0:02,8/19/16 13:33

i have a date time format, i'm trying to do if it is between 12 Am to 8 AM it is night otherwise it is day?

I'm doing something inwrong excel formula

Pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula:

```
=IF(MOD(A1,1)<8/24,"night","day")
```